# Display details of directories in a path - bash scripting assignment

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have an assignment where I need to create a script. I would like some help. I have been struggling and at this point I am lost and don't know how to proceed. I have to create a script that would take a path ensuring all the items in the path are directories and then proceed to display directory details like this.

If **`./pathdisplay ~unx510/sample.dir1/testdir1`** is entered, this is displayed:

```
Owner   Group   Other   Filename 
-----   -----   -----   -------- 

r w x   r - x   r - x   / 

r w x   r - x   r - x   home 

r w x   - - x   - - x   unx510 

r w x   r - x   r - x   sample.dir1 

r w x   r - x   r - x   testdir1 
  Links: 4  Owner: unx510  Group: users  Size: 229  Modified: Feb 22 2015



Valid commands:  u(p)  d(own)  q(uit)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: ./pathdisplay [ dir-name ]" >&2
    exit 1

elif [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    echo "$1 is not a valid directory name" >&2
    exit 1
else 
    allDirectories=$(tr '/.' '\n' < <(printf "%s" $1))
    numOfDirectories=$(tr '/.' '\n' < <(printf "%s" $1) | wc -l)

    SAVEIFS=$IFS   
    IFS=$'\n'      
    directories=($allDirectories) 
    IFS=$SAVEIFS

    for (( i=0; i<${#directories[@]}; i++ ))
    do
        if [ $i -le 0 ]; then
            $(ls  ${directories[$i]})
        else
               tempIndex=$i 
        previousDirectory=${directories[i--]}
            $(ls '$previousDirectory/'${directories[$i]})
        fi
    done


    exit 0
fi
```

I don't quite get how to iterate through the directories. As I need to specify the previous directory. And then to display the screen like that using commands to display permissions and details. Any help would be appreciated.

https://ideone.com/Dhj7Sq - link to bash script so far

http://czegel.com/seneca/unx510-dps918/assign1a/Assign1a.html - assignment specifications

http://czegel.com/seneca/unx510-dps918/assign1a/Assign1b.html - assignment screenshots

Comment: You could simply remove everything after the last `/` (including the `/`) on each iteration until no `/` is left.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'find' command to list all directories you want, and you can use stat to generate output

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d|xargs stat -c "%A %n, links:%h, owner:%U, group:%G, size:%B, modified:%y"
```

Or you can just take only find command to iterate elements by loop and generate more formatted output

Comment: but find -maxdepth would lead to other trees and subdirectories. I need to find the stat for each files given only in the path. For example with pathdisplay ~unx510/sample.dir1/testdir1 only stat for unx510, sample.dir1 and testdir1 would be displayed. Any idea on how to loop through the files in the path and display their stat details?

Comment: Oh, I though you need only directories.
Then remove "-type d" (directories only)

"maxdepth 1" means that you are locked in the path, and will not go into subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `for` loop with the following:

```
    for dir in "${directories[@]}"
    do
        stat -c "%A  %n" "$dir"
        cd "$dir"
    done
```

The above should give you some hints towards your goal.